# Select one of the 3 lowest values randomly in MySQL: using ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: mysql, random

I would like to display first 3 photos of the car randomly and I don't want to get every time the same car picture. 
One of the first three photos should be displayed because I don't want 15th photo of car boot shown on the first page.
So I have ordering column which looks like for instance 11,12,18,24,66,88,99.
I would like to display randomly 11,12 or 18 photo.
Any idea?

Comment: 11,12 or 18 means lowest values right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` to randomize a set of rows or values.

```
SELECT T1.image FROM 
    (
        SELECT image FROM carphotos ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 3        -- select lowest 3
    ) T1
    ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1         --select one of lowest 3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will be slow on larger data sets however - an intractable problem.

Comment: T1 is table one? So it shoud be like this, right? "SELECT image FROM ( SELECT image FROM carphotos ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 3 ) carphotos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1"

Comment: It doesn't work for me guys. I will list three with lowest ID and then use random function in PHP to get random one.

Comment: please mark it answer... So that others can benefit from this question